# 32.0.0 not a valid SDK version

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk, expo, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to test out an app I'm developing on Node.js and I am utilizing expo to test the app. I've tried to update the versions to see if it will fix anything. When I scan the tunnel QR code from my Ubuntu virtual machine I still get the same errors. Any help or clarifications would be greatly appreciated! I have attached screenshots to show which versions of Node.js and Expo I'm on as well as the error message I'm retrieving.

Node and Expo Versions
[image: Node and Expo Versions]

Expo Error
[image: Expo Error]

Comment: `32.0.0` vs `3.20.0` there's a difference, can you spot it?

Comment: Yes I see the difference. If you look at the screenshots, it says that 32.0.0 is not a valid sdk version but the following versions are compatible.

Comment: but you have version 3.20.0 - and there is no version 32, or 35 or 36 ... are you sure you know what package the error is referring to (oh, wait, there does seem to be a 37)

Comment: I see what your talking about. I'm confused to how the version of expo on my virtual machine is 3.20.0 but it gives me the error where 32.0.0 is not compatible when I test it using my android device.

Answer (score 0):

You should update Expo to SDK 34 or higher. Because the Expo client doesn't support the version lower SDK 34.

Comment: Would you know how I update Expo to SDK 34 or higher? I'm not sure if its my expo app on my android device that is giving me that error or expo version on my Ubuntu virtual machine?

Comment: You can follow [this document](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/)

Comment: Thank you. If I deal with any further issues, could I still reach out to you?